# Is it good to use CookieStore for below scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies

My server side application set *jsessionId http only* cookie, and then this application wants that each and every client has to send this in Payload Header to verify session integrity.

As I know that I cannot extract http only cookies through javascript.

So what I did is I have created one cookie using $cookieStore of Angular with name sessionId with the value of JsessionId retrieved from server in the first Request, then for suqsequent request I am reading the values from cookie using $cookieStore.get...

So want to know, is it the only way to do this, or there is any thing better then this

Answer (score 0):

You approach seem good.
You can change the storage by some local.storage stuff. But in term of security is globally the same than a cookie.